# Protractor progress output

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm setting up some protractor tests,everything works cool.I would just like some more info as each test as it passes /fails .

This is what I'm currently doing

```
     this.doTabCount = function (expectedCount){

       qsPage.statementTabExist().then(function () {
         qsPage.allTabs().count().then(function (count) {
           if(expect(expectedCount).toBe(expectedCount)){
             console.log('------------- Tabcount passed :) -------------');
           }else{
             console.log('------------- Tabcount FAILED :( -------------');
           }
         });
       });

     };
```

I'm pretty sure there must be a better way to display proper output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When and where do you call this `doTabCount()` function? Thanks.

Comment: Code does not work very well in here

Comment: in the it('whatever') I call a page object with that method

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you use jasmine spec reporters

This has clear instructions on how to do this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

// add jasmine spec reporter
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'all'}));
```